# CompositeTransform.TranslateY not works if end point is 0

Tags: uwp

I have no issues in transforming an UIElement, if the end point is given some value other than 0. If end point is 0 and start point in non-zero value, it does not animate. However it works with the same values in xaml without any issues. Where am I doing wrong?

```
        // Not works
        var startPoint = -200;
        var endPoint = 0;

        // works
        //var startPoint = 0;
        //var endPoint = 200;

        // Create the transform
        var moveTransform = new CompositeTransform();
        uIElement.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        uIElement.RenderTransform = moveTransform;
        var storyboard = new Storyboard();

        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames animationKeyFrames2 = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

        var keyFrameStart2 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
        keyFrameStart2.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0));
        keyFrameStart2.Value = startPoint;

        var keyFrameEnd2 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
        keyFrameEnd2.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        keyFrameEnd2.Value = endPoint;

        animationKeyFrames2.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrameEnd2);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationKeyFrames2,
            "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animationKeyFrames2, uIElement);
        storyboard.Children.Add(animationKeyFrames2);

        storyboard.Begin();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following code under the code `keyFrameStart2.Value = startPoint;` to add the `keyFrameStart2` to `animationKeyFrames2.KeyFrames` to set the start point:

```
animationKeyFrames2.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrameStart2);
```